# animation to each row in uitableview

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

How can I add animation to each row for `UITableView` in the beginning? I want an animation effect from left to right or right to left effect for every row.

Relevant code that does not get the expected effect:

```
float originalY = cell.frame.origin.y;
float originalH = cell.bounds.size.height;

[UITableViewCell animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewRowAnimationLeft animations:^{
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, (originalY + originalH), cell.bounds.size.width, 0);

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Animation is complete");
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout source code at [Animated-TableViewCell](https://github.com/Seitk/Animated-TableViewCell).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

```
+ (id)indexPathWithIndexes:(const NSUInteger [])indexes length:(NSUInteger)length;
```

Ex :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:HERE_PASS_INDEXES length:HERE_PASS_LENGTH];
[your_table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Or use as :

```
    - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;

// Make the index paths //

NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
NSIndexPath* indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];
NSIndexPath* indexPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2];
NSIndexPath* indexPath4 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:2];
// Add them in an index path array
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, indexPath2,indexPath3,indexPath4, nil];


[your_tablename reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do place that code? If it is in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it means its too soon because the table isn't drawn yet.

Try reloading the tavleview, setting the cells the initial frame in cellForRow.( if you want it coming in from the left, give it the tableView.width as the x point.)
Once the reload is complete, then create a function that goes over the cells and call the animation block you wrote.